# How do I pass multiple arguments to the same method without it returning just 1?

Tags: ruby

```
def hello(world, bob)
  p hello "#{world}"
  p hello "#{bob}"
end
```

When I run that code it sees only one argument.

How do change my method so I can return `"Hello world"` and `"Hello bob"`.

Comment: Show us how you are calling the method.

Comment: *"When I run that code"* - how do you run it? *"it sees only one argument"* - is that an error message?

Comment: A crazy question though. What do you mean calling `p(hello("#{world}"))` ?

Comment: This won't even run. How are you calling it? It should be giving you an error (see @Stefan 's comment). What does that say?

Answer (score 1):

You could have it take an unlimited amount of input as well with `*args`

```
def hello(*args)

  args.each do |word|
    puts "Hello #{word}"
  end

end
```

If you want to have the word `and` in between you could do it like this.

```
def hello(*args)

  args = args.map do |word|
    "Hello #{word}"
  end

  puts args.join(" and ")
end
```

Comment: Or you can use `args.map{|s| "Hello #{s}"}.join(" and ")`

Answer (score 0):

Bcs. in your code you have `p hello "#{world}"` and this code is same like `hello("world")`.
so you call method `hello` with one parram.

```
def hello(world, bob)
  p "Hello #{world}"
  p "Hello #{bob}"
end

hello("World", "Bob")
# => Hello World
# => Hello Bob
```

If you wanna return this two strings you just modify method like this

```
def hello(world, bob)
  return "Hello #{world}", "Hello #{bob}"
end

hello("World", "Bob")
# => [Hello World, Hello Bob]
```

OR

```
def hello(world, bob)
  ["Hello #{world}", "Hello #{bob}"]
end

hello("World", "Bob")
# => [Hello World, Hello Bob]
```

Comment: hmm. I entered the code and it is still saying it has the wrong number of arguments.

Answer (score 0):

This method will return `Hello world` & `Hello bob`

```
def hello(first, second)
  puts "Hello #{first}"
  puts "Hello #{second}"
end

hello("world", "bob")

=> Hello world
   Hello bob
```

[image: Example]